# Is it possible to delete all current SEO and start it from the beginning?

Tags: seo

My website has got hacked and all the SEO is showing PORN content with my site link.

I have requested to google search console service for removing those content but I think that not going to work because they have processed the request but still I am seeing the old content with porn and unwanted seo data.

My question is - can I start SEO from the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

*To answer the actual question: No, not that I am aware of.*

If this problem was a short period of time, don't worry about it too much. Time will fix this.

**Do make sure you've got your 404's properly**. If a page doesn't exists, return 404 to indicate that this page no longer exists. Result will steadily be removed from the search results.
**Also make sure this won't happen again.** If you keep getting this, then your site has poor security, I don't want to visit such pages and hope those kinds of pages do get a negative worth.
**Make sure your normal SEO techniques are up to par**. It's important that your site functions normal. Sitemaps, navigation, proper errorpages. The easier the site is for a bot, the faster it'll go.

If you do this, it won't be fixed instantly. Some pages will be removed/updated rather quick (few days), others may take a bit longer (1 to 3 weeks). You can not speed this up.

Comment: if time can fix this then how long it will take. I have increased the security and removed malware, now it wont happen again. But I lost all the ranking and google search console is still showing me porn keywords and bad dirty urls :(

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from my personal experience, it is possible when you delete the site; Totally remove it, wait until the major search engines will remove all results, and basically that's it.

You could even manually bulk remove all site pages from the "Search Console" (Google), or any other similar Webmaster tools interface to hasten this process.

### If the site is alive

manually bulk remove all site pages from the "Search Console" (Google), or any other similar Webmaster tools interface. After you did that, disallow these pages from the robots.txt file [as described in this article](http://www.robotstxt.org/faq/prevent.html).

This will be faster than just creating the disallow command without the manuall removal.

---

In this way, the site itself will keep being accessible to anyone but just not to robots.txt respecting crawlers.

Comment: thanks for the response but site is live so I cant remove it and also I tried the **Search Console**, removed all the URLs which was coming and then after sometime I added them again but no luck. it has same unwanted content :(

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check.

Comment: There are some severe conditions that mark a domain for a long time, however, this would be deliberate conditions such as spam (significant spam). It is a matter of trust metrics. Otherwise, for a site that was simply hacked for a period, simply fixing the site will do the trick just fine. Search engines are aware of and very forgiving of sites that are compromised. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a a few specific pages you can remove them from Google search engine in Google Webmaster Tools. Go to Google Index > Remove URLs > Temporary hide.

Comment: I did this and removed all the links but its still in the main domain URL which I can't hide it :(

Answer (score 0):

> My website has got hacked and all the SEO is showing PORN content with my site link.

Here's what I suggest.

Check all configuration files related to your site. This includes .htaccess files and httpd.conf if you use apache. Make sure that the configuration appears normal.

If you notice any settings involving serving different content based on a certain IP address, then fix that right away, then use different tools such as "fetch as google" and "page-speed insights". I suggest page-speed insights because it scans new versions of your pages.

If your server configuration seems fine, then check your web page configuration settings through the administration screens in your CMS (if applicable) to see if any odd configuration lines are put in. Perhaps the hacker added some line in it to redirect certain pages to porn.

Once you done all that, then create a sitemap for all your URLs and resubmit it to Google Search Console so that it can scan your pages again for indexing. It also helps to select the gear icon, site settings, then "Limit Google's maximum crawl rate" then move the slider all the way to the right.

Because I don't know the total number of URLs that you have for your site, I'm going to predict that you should see some results in a week.